# Facebook PHP SDK fails to obtain token if redirect URL has the code parameter

Tags: facebook-php-sdk, facebook-oauth

I am attempting OAuth authentication using the Facebook PHP SDK v5.6.1.
When the browser returns to the redirect URL, I am unable to exchange the authorization code for an access token. Instead I get a `redirect_uri_mismatch` error:

`Invalid redirect: https://.../ callback does not match one of the registered values.`

(The text may not be exact because it had to be translated)

I debugged the Facebook SDK and found that the cause of this error is the `code` parameter passed back on the request URL. Normally the SDK infers the redirect URL from the PHP request, but when I manually supply the redirect URL to the SDK without the `code` parameter then the token exchange succeeds.

My goal, is to upgrade the SDK from an older version with a minimum of code changes, so I would like to avoid manually supplying the redirect URL if possible.

Inside the `getAccessToken` SDK method, the SDK takes care to remove the `state` parameter from the URL, but does nothing about removing the `code` parameter, which evidently needs to be removed.

In my app settings for `Facebook Login` I have strict mode switched off.

What else should I do to make the request URL functional as the redirect URL?
Something must be off because I don't see anyone else having an issue with this.

Answer (score 1):

I carefully compared the mismatched url's and found one to be erroneous. The protocol said https but it also had port 80 specified. Turns out my apache reverse proxy headers were misconfigured.

```
RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto 'https'
RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Host 'hostname'
RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Port '443'
```